# Analytic integral of diverging function

Tags: integration, regularization

Is it possible to obtain the result of the following integral analytically?

$$\int_0^x \cfrac{{\rm d}u}{1-u^n}$$

I've tried using quadrature, but the function goes to infinity at $u=1$, hence the integral.

**EDIT**

I suppose an analytic solution is not possible, so is there any way to calculate it numerically for $u>1$? I managed to write:

```
from math import *
from scipy.integrate import quad
f = lambda u,n: 1./(1.-(u**n))
eps = 0.0001; n=2.6;
# from 0 to 1.005
print quad(lambda x:f(x,n),0.0,1.-eps)[0]+ quad(lambda x:f(x,n) ,1.+eps,1.005)[0]
```

I implemented the Cauchy principle value method in python 2.7 using scipy. Is there are particular reason for it not to work. For `(u=1.005, n=2.6, x=u)` the result should have been 2.022 (according to [this](http://books.google.com.tr/books?id=D0UnWdcIRK0C&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=varied%20flow%20function%20table&source=bl&ots=UnvGFjy5jN&sig=ODRMDqpB3zlz-TGn8A7XaiRNLqY&hl=tr&sa=X&ei=v5DpUNrJMsbctAaG0IGYBA&sqi=2&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) (*Open-Channel Flow* by Subhash C. Jain, p78)). Instead, it is 2.48. Am I missing something? Can we say that $$\int_0^{x+\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n} = \int_0^{x-\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}$$

Here are the numerical solutions that are supposedly correct:

[image]

**Solution:**

Here is a snippet in python2.7 using the `hyp2f1()` function from the `mpmath` package

```
def F(u,n):
    if u < 1:
        return u*mpmath.hyp2f1(1/n,1,1/n+1,u**n)
    elif u >1:
        return (u**(1-n))/(n-1)* \
            mpmath.hyp2f1(1-1/n, 1 , 2-1/n ,u**(-1*n)) #+ pi/n/tan(pi/n)
    else:
        return 0.
```

Comment: You have a $u$ in the integrand and a $u$ as a limit of integration.  Should the integration limit be $n$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas No, it is $u$. The function is used as the "varied flow function" in hydraulics.

Comment: @nrs Do you want $$\int_0^x \dfrac{du}{1-u^n}?$$ It is preferred to use different variables for the integrand and the limits to avoid possible confusion.

Comment: Also, look at here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F%281-u^n%29 . I've tried implementing the hypergeometric function, but I failed.

Comment: @Marvis Please look at my first comment.

Comment: @nrs For me all the $u$'s appear the same. Kindly change the variable name.

Comment: @Marvis I changed it now

Comment: @nrs Thanks. Is $x < 1$?. Else the integral will not converge.

Comment: @Marvis $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$. I guess that's the problem ^^

Comment: I think you should say the function goes to infnity at $1$, not that it "goes to infinity at $u$."

Comment: nrs, could you take a screenshot of the page(s) from that book?  I can't view them.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I did.

Comment: @nrs: for any $x\ne1$, we have that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^{x+\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n} = \lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_0^{x-\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}
$$
However, the Cauchy Principal Value assumes that
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\int_0^{1+\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n} - \int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}\right)\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can at least give your integral a name.  Suppose $0 \leq x<1$ so that the integral converges.

Letting $u = v^{1/n}$, the integral becomes

$$
\frac{1}{n} \int_0^{x^n} v^{\frac{1}{n}-1}(1-v)^{-1}\,dv = \frac{1}{n}B\left(x^n;\,\frac{1}{n},\,0\right),
$$

where $B(z;p,q)$ is the incomplete beta function.  According to [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html), we can also write this as a hypergeometric function:

$$
x\cdot{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,\frac{1}{n}+1;\,x^n\right).
$$

---

It appears (based on numerical evidence) that the principal value of the integrand is given by

$$
\text{PV} \int_0^x \frac{du}{1-u^n} = \operatorname{Re}\left[x\cdot{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,\frac{1}{n}+1;\,x^n\right)\right].
$$

---

**This is in regards to the table posted in the question.**  They are not using the principal value of the integral; they are using a related quantity which differs from the principal value by a function depending only on $n$.

Let $0 < \epsilon < \min\{1,x-1\}$ and split the integral up into two parts,

$$
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{du}{1-u^n} + \int_{1+\epsilon}^{x} \frac{du}{1-u^n} \\
&\qquad = (1-\epsilon)\cdot{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,\frac{1}{n}+1;\,(1-\epsilon)^n\right) + \int_{1+\epsilon}^{x} \frac{du}{1-u^n}.
\end{align*}
$$

Making the substitution $u=1/v$ in the remaining integral gives

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{1+\epsilon}^{x} \frac{du}{1-u^n} &= -\int_{1/x}^{1/(1+\epsilon)}\frac{v^{n-2}}{1-v^n}\,dv \\
&= \int_0^{1/x}\frac{v^{n-2}}{1-v^n}\,dv - \int_0^{1/(1+\epsilon)}\frac{v^{n-2}}{1-v^n}\,dv.
\end{align*}
$$

Both of these integrals are treated the same way.  We proceed as before, letting $v=w^{1/n}$.  This gives

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^a \frac{v^{n-2}}{1-v^n}\,dv &= \frac{1}{n} \int_0^{a^n} w^{\frac{n-1}{n}-1} (1-w)^{-1}\,dw \\
&= \frac{a^{n-1}}{n-1}\, {}_2F_1\left(1-\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,2-\frac{1}{n};\,a^n\right),
\end{align*}
$$

so that

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{1+\epsilon}^{x} \frac{du}{1-u^n} &= \frac{x^{1-n}}{n-1}\, {}_2F_1\left(1-\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,2-\frac{1}{n};\,x^{-n}\right) \\
&\qquad - \frac{(1+\epsilon)^{1-n}}{n-1}\, {}_2F_1\left(1-\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,2-\frac{1}{n};\,(1+\epsilon)^{-n}\right).
\end{align*}
$$

Thus

$$
\text{PV} \int_0^x \frac{du}{1-u^n} = \frac{x^{1-n}}{n-1}\, {}_2F_1\left(1-\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,2-\frac{1}{n};\,x^{-n}\right) + f(n),
\tag{1}
$$

where

$$
\begin{align*}
f(n) &= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left\{(1-\epsilon)\cdot{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,\frac{1}{n}+1;\,(1-\epsilon)^n\right) \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad \left. - \frac{(1+\epsilon)^{1-n}}{n-1}\, {}_2F_1\left(1-\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,2-\frac{1}{n};\,(1+\epsilon)^{-n}\right)\right\} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{n} \cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)
\tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$

if $n>1$.  The last equality $(2)$ follows directly from [robjohn's work](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/271803/5531) by letting $x \to \infty$ in $(1)$.  So, in summary,

> For $x<1$,
>   $$
> \int_0^x \frac{du}{1-u^n} = x\cdot{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,\frac{1}{n}+1;\,x^n\right),
> $$
>   and for $x>1$ and $n>1$,
>   $$
> \text{PV} \int_0^x \frac{du}{1-u^n} = \frac{x^{1-n}}{n-1}\, {}_2F_1\left(1-\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,2-\frac{1}{n};\,x^{-n}\right) + \frac{\pi}{n} \cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right).
> $$

In computing their table, they seem to have assumed that $f(n) = 0$.  Indeed, their table is exactly equal to the one generated by

$$
g(n,x) = \text{PV} \int_0^x \frac{du}{1-u^n} - \frac{\pi}{n} \cot\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right).
$$

For example,

$$
\begin{align*}
g(2.6,1.01) &\approx 1.75625, \\
g(2.6,1.02) &\approx 1.4927, \\
g(2.6,1.03) &\approx 1.33979, \\
g(2.6,1.04) &\approx 1.23215, \\
g(2.6,1.05) &\approx 1.14932.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: @nrs: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271323/can-this-function-be-expressed-in-terms-of-other-well-known-functions/271342#271342).

Comment: Thanks for the name. I tried writing the series in explicit form. Would it be equal to:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \cfrac{1 \cdot 1/n}{1+1/n} \cfrac{(x^n)^i}{i!} $$
?

Comment: Do you know whether for $x\gt1$, this function agrees with the Cauchy Principal Value of the integral?

Comment: @robjohn it doesn't look like it.  Mathematica returns a complex number for the hypergeometric function when $x > 1$.

Comment: @robjohn I take it back.  See the edit.

Comment: I just computed the PV from $0$ to $\infty$; it comes to $\frac\pi n\cot\left(\frac\pi n\right)$.

Comment: @nrs I found out how they calculated that table.

Comment: @robjohn, do you think the equality in $(*)$ follows from your contour integration?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: judging from the previous equation as $x\to\infty$, I would say yes :-)

Comment: @AntonioVargas & robjohn Amazing work! Thanks for all your efforts. I wish I could give more than just reputation. I must choose this one as the answer, however, since it is a complete solution to the problem.

Comment: @AntonioVargas There is a point I could not understand. In $(2)$, how is the expression on the rhs equal to $\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}$?

Comment: Also, glad I could help, @nrs :)

Comment: @nrs My deleted comment was correct.  I should wait to wake up more before coming here!  I'll repost it just below.

Comment: The expression in $(1)$ is equal to the PV of the integral as defined at the top of robjohn's answer, where $f(n)$ defined just below by the limit.  That $f(n) = (\pi/n)\cot(\pi/n)$ follows from robjohn's calculation that $\text{PV}\int_0^\infty = (\pi/n)\cot(\pi/n)$.  Indeed, if $n>1$ then $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{1-n}}{n-1}\, {}_2F_1\left(1-\frac{1}{n},\,1;\,2-\frac{1}{n};\,x^{-n}\right) = 0$$ since ${}_2F_1(a,b;c;0) = 1$.  So, taking the limit as $x \to \infty$ in equation $(1)$ we are left with $\text{PV}\int_0^\infty = f(n)$, so that we must have $f(n) = (\pi/n)\cot(\pi/n)$.

Answer (score 4):

The integral can be given a value for $x\gt1$ using the [Cauchy Principal Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). That is, for $x\gt1$,
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}
=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\int_0^{1-\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}
+\int_{1+\epsilon}^x\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}\right)
$$

---

**Cauchy Principal Value over $\mathbf{\mathbb{R}^+}$**

Consider the contour

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216), we get
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^n}=\frac\pi n\csc\left(\frac\pi n\right)
$$
Thus, the integral on the blue line is
$$
-e^{i\pi/n}\frac\pi n\csc\left(\frac\pi n\right)=-\frac\pi n\cot\left(\frac\pi n\right)-i\frac\pi n
$$
The residue of $\frac1{1-u^n}$ at $u=1$ is $-\frac1n$. Therefore, the integral along the clockwise red semicircle is
$$
i\frac\pi n
$$
Since there are no singularities inside the contour, the total integral over the contour is $0$. Thus, the integral over the perforated green line must be
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}=\frac\pi n\cot\left(\frac\pi n\right)
$$

---

**Self-Contained Argument**

Using the contour above and separating real and imaginary parts, we get that
$$
\begin{align}
\color{#00A000}{\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}}+\color{#C00000}{i\frac\pi n}
&=\color{#0000FF}{e^{i\pi/n}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^n}}\\
&=\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi n\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi n\right)\right)\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^n}
\end{align}
$$
Looking at the imaginary part, we get
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1+u^n}=\frac\pi n\csc\left(\frac\pi n\right)
$$
Then looking at the real part, we get
$$
\mathrm{PV}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}=\frac\pi n\cot\left(\frac\pi n\right)
$$

Comment: Can we say that $\int_0^{x+\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n} = \int_0^{x-\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}$

Comment: Waaaay cleaner than some hypergeometric.  Nice.

Comment: @robjohn I also edited the question with some code to clarify my problem.

Comment: @nrs: Cauchy Principal Value essentially assumes that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{1+\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{1-u^n}=0
$$